# Automating through multiple path locations and exporting file names

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a script which works but is not very elegant. It merges csv files, outputs a new file, filters that file to the required conditions, then outputs the filtered file, which is the file I want. I then repeat the process for every month.

Rather than altering this code to process every month (I have 5 more years worth of data to go), I would like to automate the path directory part and export csv file names that change from one month (and year) to the next.

See snippet of Jan and Feb below:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil
path = r"C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\20xx01"
os.chdir(path)
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
    combined_csv.to_csv("201401.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

    grab1 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\20xx01\201401.csv'
    move1 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\2014\2014-01.csv'

shutil.move(grab1,move1)

fd = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\2014\2014-01.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(fd)
irishsea = df[(df.lat_bin >= 5300) & (df.lat_bin <= 5500) & (df.lon_bin >= -650) & (df.lon_bin <= -250)]
irishsea.to_csv("2014-01_irishsea.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

grab2 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\20xx01\2014-01_irishsea.csv'
move2 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\2014\2014-01-IrishSea.csv'

shutil.move(grab2,move2)
```

I then repeat it for Feb data but have to update the path locations.

```
#process feb data
   path = r"C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\20xx02"
os.chdir(path)

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
combined_csv.to_csv("201402.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

grab1 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\20xx02\201402.csv'
move1 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\2014\2014-02.csv'

shutil.move(grab1,move1)

fd = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\2014\2014-02.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(fd)
irishsea = df[(df.lat_bin >= 5300) & (df.lat_bin <= 5500) & (df.lon_bin >= -650) & (df.lon_bin <= -250)]
irishsea.to_csv("2014-02_irishsea.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

grab2 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\20xx02\2014-02_irishsea.csv'
move2 = r'C:\Users\jonathan.capanda\Documents\Fishing_DataBase\gfw_data\100_deg_data\daily_csvs\2014\2014-02-IrishSea.csv'

shutil.move(grab2,move2)
```

Comment: why do you combine the csv then move them manually? can you expand on the logic a little more

Comment: hi, i have a file for each day of the year so i am combining to minimise the data to a monthly format for each year to make it more usable. I use the shutil.move to move the file so not doing that manually, i need to move it because the list of files is in one folder which after combining the export file ends up but i want the combined file to be placed in another file before i filter it, which needs moving as well. Bit long winded i know.

Comment: Just for total clarity, you read in files which are split by day into a single file, you then want partition them into a monthly folder structure, yes? what happens to the daily files. and is there a date column inside the file or do you get the date from the file name ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following. Keep in mind that the second number of range (the stop value) needs to be one value higher than you intend.

```
for year in range(2014, 2020):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        if month < 10:
            month_as_string = "0" + str(month)
        else:
            month_as_string = str(month)
        date = "%s\%s-%s" % (year, year, month_as_string)
        pathname = 'YOUR\FILEPATH\HERE' + date + 'irishsea.csv'
```

You can learn more about string formatting here https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting

Comment: thanks for the example, will give it a go and report back.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have questions.